# How to stop contact & case creation in chat using ExtraPrechatDetails & ExtraPrechatInfo?

Tags: deployment, omnichannel, pre-chat, einstein-chatbot, embedded-services

**I am not using a Prechat form would that automatically avoid case/contact creation while chat**
If not then what to do to avoid it using ExtraPreChatInfo & ExtraPreChatDetails.What is the meaning of display to agent parameter because true /false I don't see a change anywhere?